# How to fetch a value from the Json response array in android?

Tags: android, json

I am new to android and JSON parsing. Here i have my json response that i get. Now i have several such response in my jsonarray. What i would like to know is how do i fetch a single value from this response.

i.e how can i fetch only "id" from these response:

```
 {"id":"c200","gender":"male","phone":{"office":"00 000000","home":"00 000000","mobile":"+91 0000000000"},"address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","email":"ravi@gmail.com","name":"Ravi Tamada"}

{"id":"c201","gender":"male","phone":{"office":"00 000000","home":"00 000000","mobile":"+91 0000000000"},"address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","email":"johnny_depp@gmail.com","name":"Johnny Depp"}
```

I want only id of both these respones.

My code is

```
JSONObject jobject = jparse.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    contacts = jobject.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < contacts.length() ; i++)
    {
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

        Log.i("TAG", "STRING VALUE:" + contacts.getString(i));

                 String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                 String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                 String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                 String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want all id then remove for loop and just put

`JSONObject j = contacts.getJSONObject(0);`

`String id = j.getString("id");`

it will give the first object id that is only : c200

Answer (score 0):

You got response from server in as json.
You can get only id as shown below code.

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(response);//response= your json string.

String id = json.getString("id");//id = param in your response
```